# heroku ssl certificate giving certificate name mismatch errors

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I followed all the steps for adding an ssl certificate to my heroku-hosted rails site with a custom domain add-on, which is also a facebook app and uses omniauth.  It seemed to be working for a while, and then I noticed that I couldn't authenticate within the canvas app on IE8.  In troubleshooting that, I noticed a lot of name mismatch errors in all the browsers (chrome, firefox, IE9).  When I did a test on an ssl checker site, I got the following

None of the common names in the certificate match the name that was entered (www.mydomainname.com). You may receive an error when accessing this site in a web browser. Learn more about name mismatch errors.
    Common name: *.heroku.com
SANs: *.heroku.com, heroku.com
Organization: Heroku, Inc.
Location: San Francisco, California, US
Valid from August 25, 2010 to August 29, 2013
Serial Number: 056e3972a0d34ffe9cd364eae3196171
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3

```
Common name: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
```

Organization: DigiCert Inc
Location: US
Valid from April 2, 2007 to April 2, 2022
Serial Number: 0851f959814145cabde024e212c9c20e
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA

```
Common name: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
```

Organization: DigiCert Inc
Location: US
Valid from September 30, 2006 to July 26, 2014
Serial Number: 1116160165 (0x428740a5)
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: Entrust.net Secure Server Certification Authority

Am I stuck with it, or is there a way to fix the name mismatches heroku-hosted sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly error, but in case someone does the same...

I followed all the directions and created "https"://secure.myapp.com, but "https"://www.myapp.com was still pointing to an IP.  When I switched "https"://www.myapp.com cname to point to the url provided by my ssl provider, I still received mismatch errors, but at least they were to "https"://secure.myapp.com.  Solution?  Purchased a new ssl license for www and pointed www.myapp.com to the provided url.

Comment: Also had to delete the custom domain for secure in order to get it to work.